# Developing "classful" applications using javascript on nodejs

Tags: node.js, class, design-patterns, saas

I'm working on an advanced SaaS application that relies heavily on classes and the relating logic.

I've tried to "map" entities to objects as it should be done , but that's not resolving the issue for my case as a lot of problems when trying to implement the design patterns related to OOP.

Besides , there is some ambiguities on how to use properly "class" in nodejs (should I export the class in order to instanciate it somewhere else or what?).
Help appreciated , even with suggestions.

Comment: What's the question? *a lot of problems when trying to implement the design patterns related to OOP* - if you need help with these problems, consider explaining them in details, preferably with https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . *should I export the class in order to instanciate it somewhere else or what?* - you need to export anything to use it in another module in Node.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, I'm interested in knowing is someone has done something similar in the past .. I've divided my project into layers and I need to apply OOP design patterns not only middleware logic.

Comment: Similar to what? You didn't show anything, and the description is too obscure. Even if somebody had same concerns as you, there's no way to tell without mind-reading. Please, provide an example that clearly shows the problems you have. This may be a question https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but it's impossible to say because there's no code to review.

Comment: It's an architectural problem , it has nothing to do with code.

Comment: Showing the code is the best way to make other users understand your problem. You never mentioned what actual problems are. Yes, it's possible to apply OOP principles to Node application. Somehow. The way it should be done depends on your case.